# How to do a quick equation on CSHTML to show 3MB?

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, view

Currently I am getting the maximum file size value from the Web.config file. When I run the application I have text to display the max file size, currently this showing 3145728, however I want it to show 3 MB. I have declared a variable at the top of the page as below

```
var maxFilesize = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["maximumfilesize"];
```

and I am showing accessing the above variable like

```
<li>File size: @maxFilesize </li>
```

I beleive I do a calculation on the lines 1024f / 1024f to get 3MB nut Im not sure how to do this in my view?

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of examples out there.

Search for "c# file size human readable"

This should help: http://codesnippets.fesslersoft.de/how-to-format-bytes-to-human-readable-file-size-in-c-and-vb-net/

Regards,

Adam.